# OpenID Connect/OAuth2 user synchronisation protocol extension

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an application consisting of (simplified) 3 parts:

- an Security-Token-Service (handling OAuth2 and OpendId-Connect) with its own seperated database (actually it's Identity Server 4 with ASP.NET Core Identity)
- an API (with a seperated database)
- and a SPA communicating with the API

Now the problem is that the database of the STS holds the user data and in the API-DB there is also a table user-accounts with the work-load-data for each user.

Currently I create the API-DB user-account on the first login of the user. Which works.

I am just wondering if there is a protocol (extension) defining a way to sync created/deleted users between an STS and other server applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be worth having a read of this and evaluating whether it fits your use-case:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_for_Cross-domain_Identity_Management